# Trying to create animated list but not sure how to get listKey from another script file?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, getter

I am trying to make my list animated, so when i delete task it plays animation. I watched few tutorials however i am not sure how to implement this into my code because they had the animatedlist and void deleteitem in the same script, where i am having in 2 different one.

Here is my code from the task_data script file

```
    void removeItem(Task task) {
//removedTask = task;

final item = _tasks.remove(task);
listKey.currentState!.removeItem(
    task,
    (context, animation) => TaskTile(
          //taskTitle: task.name,
          //isChecked: task.isDone,
          //checkboxCallback: (checkboxState) {
          //taskData.updateTask(task);
          taskTitle: task.name,
          isChecked: task.isDone,
          animation: animation, checkboxCallback: (bool) {},
          longPressCallback: () {},
        ));
notifyListeners();
saveData();
```

}

Here is my code from task_tile script

```
class TaskTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isChecked;
  final String taskTitle;
  final Function(bool?) checkboxCallback;
  final VoidCallback longPressCallback;
  final Animation<double> animation;

  TaskTile({
    required this.isChecked,
    required this.taskTitle,
    required this.checkboxCallback,
    required this.longPressCallback,
    required this.animation,
  });
```

And here is my code from tasks_list script file

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TaskData>(
      builder: (context, taskData, child) {
        return AnimatedList(
          key: _listKey,
          initialItemCount: taskData.tasks.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
            return TaskTile(
              animation: animation,
              taskTitle: taskData.tasks[index].name,
              //isChecked: Provider.of<TaskData>(context).tasks[index].isDone,
              //Provider.of<TaskData>(context).tasks = task_data. we would use LHS when we did not wrap with Consumer
              isChecked: taskData.tasks[index].isDone,
              checkboxCallback: (checkboxState) {
                HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
                taskData.updateTask(taskData.tasks[index]);
              },
              longPressCallback: () {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar(taskData));
                taskData.deleteTask(taskData.tasks[index]);
                HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
              },
            );
          },
          //itemCount: taskData.taskCount,
        );
      },
    );
```

Would really appreciate if someone can help me with this!

EDIT
--- I am getting this error right now "The argument type 'Task' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'."

- on the actual screen it displays red box range error and I'm not sure how to fix those

Answer (score 1):

Use it as a global key to access the keys from other classes

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    //Create it as Global key
    final myListKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

      final String title;

      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      final widgets = [
        Container(color: Colors.red),
        Container(color: Colors.green),
        Container(color: Colors.yellow),
      ];
      int currentIndex = 0;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: AnimatedList(
            key: myListKey,
            initialItemCount: widgets.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index, animation) {
              return Container(
                height: 100,
                child: widgets[index],
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for help! It does work, something i been looking for. However i am getting some error on my screen saying in red box `RangeError (Index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1` ... Also, when I delete the task it disappears without the animation but the other tasks animate upwards.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtfItHwFlZ8&ab_channel=Flutter

Comment: You have to use key to add or remove the items

Comment: I have used the key to remove in my task_data (Updated the code), however i am struggling as when i put "index" it says undefined name. if i use "task" which is my index of list it says `The argument type 'Task' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.`

Comment: While deleting do you have the index accessible  then use that else pass the index to delete the operation widget from AnimatedItem ListBuiler

Comment: Don't get it :| been trying to figure it out in my code for an hour now.

Comment: Follow the video

Comment: I did about 5+ times

Comment: Goto My Profile >website > about  >Telegram link is there you can ping me

Comment: Nothing displays on your website when i click it